# How can I upload Document using React Native on Google Drive's Specific Folder?

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-drive-api

I've already gone through **Google Drive API documentation**. But am unable to understand how to implement the Document uploader in React Native.
I've obtained `API key` but there's something called `YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN` and between all of these I am stuck.
Can I have some reference including drive API call or code/scenario of api_key & ACCESS_TOKEN

```
 curl --request POST \
'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?enforceSingleParent=true&ignoreDefaultVisibility=true&keepRevisionForever=true&supportsAllDrives=true&supportsTeamDrives=true&useContentAsIndexableText=true&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{}' \
--compressed
```

Here's I've got the Curl request from Try It of Drive https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `access token` is part of the OAuth 2.0 protocol that Google APIs use for authentication and authorization. The process, as summarized [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2), is the following:

> To begin, obtain OAuth 2.0 client credentials from the [Google API Console](https://console.developers.google.com/). Then your client application requests an access token from the Google Authorization Server, extracts a token from the response, and sends the token to the Google API that you want to access.

Here you can see a complete guide to the OAuth 2.0 process for mobile apps, as I guess your case is: [OAuth 2.0 for Mobile & Desktop Apps](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app). The process is basically the following:

1. Create a project in [Google Cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/), enable Drive API for it and create authorization credentials. See [Prerequisites](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app#prerequisites).
2. Send a request to Google's OAuth 2.0 server to get the access token, and get the refresh and access tokens. See [Obtaining OAuth 2.0 access tokens](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app#obtainingaccesstokens).
3. Make the API request using the access token. See [Calling Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app#callinganapi).

#### Note:

- I'd suggest you to give a long read to both referenced pages.

#### Reference:

- [Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2)
- [OAuth 2.0 for Mobile & Desktop Apps](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app)